# Show value from chart when touch selected place

Tags: android

I am using `androidplot` library to show plots. And I have a question: this is any functionality to show value from chart when I touch him on specify place. For example I have a chart and I click in half of this chart and I want to see what values are in this place. is this possible?
Edit:
Ok I do something like that:

```
     private OnTouchListener myGraphTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                                 && plot.containsPoint(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                         plot.setCursorPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
                         long xAxisValue = plot.getGraphWidget()
                                         .getXVal(event.getX()).longValue();
                         double yAxisValue = plot.getGraphWidget()
                                         .getRangeCursorVal();
                         plot.getGraphWidget().setCursorLabelPaint(null);
                         String xAxisDate = new Date(xAxisValue).toLocaleString();
                         Log.d("OnGraphTouch", "X-Value: " + xAxisValue + "\nY-Value: "
                                         + yAxisValue +", "+xAxisDate);

                         Log.v("asd", ""+plot.getGraphWidget().getAxisValueLabelRegions());
                 }

                 return true;
         }
 };
```

but this solution show me all points wherever I click. If I click on chart or on white space this doesn't matter. I want to show logs only when I click on chart. Any ideas?